# rvest: how to find required css-selector

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to **scrape** parts of speeches held in parliament with the `rvest` package.
Using the css selector or chrome's inspector tool provide me with a selector, however I am unable to retrieve the intended (any) data. AFAIK, the site is also not java etc based, i.e. no RSelenium etc should be required.

here is the [link](https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00001/fnameorig_796482.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

session_1 <- "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00001/fnameorig_796482.html"

x <- session_1 %>%  
  rvest::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_element("wordsection14") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

Eventually, I would like to be able to get the text contained in all elements with the class 'wordsection*'.

Would be very grateful for any hint. Many thanks.

Comment: Since you are looking for a class=Wordsection14 and not a html tag you need use a "." before the class name, but that still won't solve it.

Comment: I don't understand what is happen with this page.  `page %>%  html_elements("div")` should return a full list of nodes (all of the WordSections)  but in this case it is only returning the first 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr The problem is not the css selectors. It's the encoding. Specify encoding = 'latin1'

```
read_html('https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00001/fnameorig_796482.html', encoding = "latin1") %>% 
  html_nodes('[class^=WordSection]') %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  length()
```

---

**Curl:**

You could also use curl.

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)

text_info <- curl_fetch_memory("https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00001/fnameorig_796482.html") %>%
  {rawToChar(.$content)} %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("[class^=WordSection]") %>%
  html_text()
```

---

**CSS Selectors:**

If you use an css attribute = value selector with starts with operator ^ to get all the nodes with class value starting with `WordSection`.

Given that there is a lot of nesting to avoid repeat material you may decide to use [nth-child range](http://nthmaster.com/) selectors or [other css selector combinations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to restrict the match list.

Write some custom function(s) to manage string cleaning.

You can of course use different css selectors if you so choose.

---

Comment: @Dave2e Still haven't narrowed down cause but hijacked java instead cos I noticed it worked with certain java implementations and returned the expected 69. Started reading the implementation details but not worked it out yet.

Comment: It's the encoding. The reason I didn't pick it up earlier, when testing encoding, was I assumed R used `latin-1` but it is `latin1`. Most frustrating.

Comment: @QHarr I understand that it's not good practice on SO, but still: Many thanks for digging into it!

Comment: You are welcome. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: Nice job! This is an easy fix. Good trick to know for the future.